# How do I handle invalid IP addresses in this port scanning program?

Tags: python, exception, ip

I am trying to create an exemption that will handle non-existent ip addresses. When I type a random ip address, for instance 122.67.254.1, the program still proceeds to scan for ports instead of
raising an exception. I need for fake IPs like this to be exempted rather than for the port scanning to proceed on a non-existent host.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime

# Clear the screen
# subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

# Ask for input
remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

# Seek user input and validate format using try block
MinRange = int(input("Enter starting port number: "))
MaxRange = int(input("Enter ending port number: "))
CheckRange = range(MinRange, MaxRange + 1, 1)


# Create a function to use the command for a given host and port
def CheckPort(host, port):
    s = socket
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# Every scan should create a new file. Check if file exists. If so, delete it
# Open file in append + read mode, create if does not exist
xfile = open("ScanResults", "w")

# Print a nice banner with information on which host we are about to scan
print("-" * 60)
print("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
print("-" * 60)

# Check what time the scan started
t1 = datetime.now()


# Using the range function to specify ports (here it will scans all ports between 1 and 1024)

# We also put in some error handling for catching errors

try:
    for port in range(MinRange, MaxRange):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result: int = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port {}:      Open".format(port))
            xfile.write(result)
        sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print("Couldn't connect to server")
    sys.exit()

# Checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

# Calculates the difference of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total = t2 - t1

# Printing the information to screen
print('Scanning Completed in: ', total)

# notify user process has finished
start = t1
end = t2
print("Task completed. Port range", MinRange, " - ", MaxRange, " has been scanned. ")
elapsed = end - start
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Scan completed at: ", dt_string)
print("Total scan time: ", elapsed, "seconds.")
#FinTup = ["Port", globals(Newvar), "is open", "\n"]
#FinOut = ''.join(FinTup)
FinTup = ["Scan completed at", str(dt_string), "\n"]
FinOut = ''.join(FinTup)
xfile.write(FinOut)
FinTup = ("Total scan time:", str(elapsed), "seconds.", "\n")
FinOut = ''.join(FinTup)
xfile.write(FinOut)
xfile.close()
```

Comment: Any chance of reducing your example to a minimal [mre]? Concentrating on the issue/problem you are having?

Comment: `non-existent ip addresses` - non-existing in what respect? What is the criteria? What issue are you having? Excluding addresses or determining which addresses to exclude? Handling the exception?

Comment: I'm trying to create an exemption for when I type in an ip address that doesn't exist. I want for it to exit code as soon as I type that ip address and hit enter rather than attempt to scan ports on it.